# How to get notified when the location of a window is changed in Linux?

Tags: linux, x11

In Linux, one can use `xwininfo` to get the location of a window. When the location of window is changed, one can run the command again. However, it's not very efficient to put the command in a loop, and run it all the time. Is that possible to get notified when the location is changed in order to run the command less time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen for [ConfigureNotify](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/window-state-change/configure.html) event of that window. To subscribe, set `StructureNotify` using xlib [XSelectInput](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSelectInput.html) (or low level - `ConfigureWindow` X11 request)

Example using JavaScript / [node-x11](https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11) (exits immediately after location or geometry of window is changed)

```
var x11 = require('x11');

var wid = Number(process.argv[2]);

x11.createClient(function(err, display) {
  var X = display.client;
  X.ChangeWindowAttributes(wid, { eventMask: x11.eventMask.StructureNotify });
  X.on('event', function(ev) {
    if (ev.name === 'ConfigureNotify') {
      console.log(ev.x, ev.y, ev.width, ev.height);
      X.close();
    }
  });
});
```